# Debug PHP 5.6 with PhpStorm and Zend Debugger

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2017.2.4, and programming with PHP 5.6 (for technical purposes).
Because I'm using PHP 5.6, since Xdebug only supports PHP 7 and upwards, I cannot use it to debug my code - hence I have to use Zend Debugger.

I've been trying to attach Zend Debugger to PhpStorm by following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqDDJfG6ip4), though it doesn't seem to work.
I'd like to be able to debug PHP similarly to how I'd debug JavaScript with Chrome Developer Tools (breakpoints, check variable values, etc.)

What I've been trying, so far:

1. Download the Zend Debugger ZIP, extract ZendDbugger.dll to `C:\xampp\php\ext` and add to `php.ini`:

   ```
   [Zend Debugger]
   zend_exxtension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\ZendDebugger.dll"
   zend_debugger_allow_hosts=localhost
   zend_debugger.expose_remotely=allowed_hosts
   ```
2. I tried clicking [this](https://i.imgur.com/nrYWcjG.png) > + > PHP Web Application > Server ... > + > Name: localhost, Host: localhost, Debugger: Zend Debugger > OK > OK
3. Set a break point, so I know that the debugger works > Shift+F10 > Enter an input into the text field and submit > PhpStorm's The break point isn't triggered

I thought that I may have missed a step due to [PhpStorm's bookmarklet instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/), so I put the Start Debugger one, restarted the webpage, entered the input, pressed Start Debugger and submitted - but no, no breakpoint was triggered.

What have I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Because I'm using PHP 5.6, since Xdebug only supports PHP 7 and upwards, I cannot use it to debug my code - hence I have to use Zend Debugger."* Just install older xdebug version -- Xdebug 2.5.5 supports even PHP 5.5.

Comment: I actually haven't thought of that. Though, I don't know which version to install. Regardless, the problem that I'm encountering wasn't solved yet.

Comment: *"Though, I don't know which version to install."* https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hHNep3Z.png - Pay attention to the bottom line please

Comment: `PHP 5.6 VC11 TS (32 bit)` -- get that file. Full link (just in case): https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11.dll

Answer (score 0):

you need to install a chrome extension to link your page to phpstorm debug functionality. something like this one : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en

Comment: as far as I remember, you should start to listen to debug calls in phpstorm, then visit the site in chrome. there is some settings to be done to connect chrome to phpstorm.

Comment: I eventually got it working somehow. I also played a bit with the httpd.conf file and somehow the PHP debugger worked

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar scenario and I could debug PHP 5.6 in PHP Storm with the following steps.

1. Installed XAMPP 5.6 via this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.40/)
2. It's bundled with php_xdebug.dll and therefore no need to download it from xdebug.org. In case you don't have it can be download from [here](https://xdebug.org/download/historical).
3. Update php.ini by appending the following lines at the end of the file.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=C:\Temp
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

4. Restart Apache Server
5. Install  '[Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en)' extension to chrome.
6. Now in PHP Storm click on  "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections" button and you should be able to hit your breakpoints.