# How to debug project with php 5.6. in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, php-5.6

Could anybody help, how to debug php project in Visual Studio Code with php 5.6.? Something like xdebug. I need to trace program.

Comment: Anything not working with XDebug?

Comment: _Side note:_ PHP 5.6 are no longer supported and hasn't gotten a single update (including security updates) in over 3,5 years, which could make it vulnerable for certain type of attacks. It's definitely time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

So this guy's answer in the link below is for PHPStorm but it worked for me. I just took out the line for IDE Key.

I'm using vscode and it worked fine.

Install xampp v5.6.40, the xdebug file is included in the installation.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=C:\Temp
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73494033/19898746